# How I can fix json structure to help spark read it properly. Different types for same key

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I'm reciving json. I don't know on which keys problem will appear. When spark see different types for same key it puts this into string and I need to have data in array type. I'm using spark 2.4 with json lib so I read jsons as 
`spark.read.json("jsonfile")`

I'm flattening my json schema to this kind of format where col name is: 
B__C 
B__somedifferentColname

Sample json look like this

```
{
   "A":[
      {
         "B":{
            "C":"Hello There"
         }
      },
      {
         "B":[
            {
               "C":"Hello"
            },
            {
               "C":"Hi"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and I would like to have this json in format like this:

```
{
   "A":[
      {
         "B":[{
            "C":"Hello There"
         }]
      },
      {
         "B":[
            {
               "C":"Hello"
            },
            {
               "C":"Hi"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

So as you can see what I have changed is added square brackets to first object.

But when I have one value as struct type and one value as a list it puts this to string so the column value will be look like:

`"[{"C":"Hello"},{"C":"Hi"}]"`

and it should look like that 
B__C
Hello
Hi
Hello There

Is anyone able to help me what trick I can use to resolve this issue? 
Team which delivers jsons to us said this is not possible to do this from thier side so we have to resolve this on our side.

Comment: There is no trick but you could look into https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html

Comment: @morfious902002 Its compliated to write own deserializer cause we don't know on which key we might have object or list. We need to scan whole json, find keys which on node have different type so in this case "B" key have different type and in this case put value of B key into list. It's seems really complicated.